# python multiprocessing IOError: [Errno232] The pipe is being closed

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deadlock

The following code will count all 750 joins and will print the results queue, but after it does that it gets stuck in deadlock.  If I assign results to multiprocessing.Queue(), the program deadlocks immediately.

```
def function(job, results):
    # do stuff
    results_q.put(stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    devices = {}
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        projectFile= f.readlines()

        jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
        results = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

        pool = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(jobs, results)) for ip in itertools.islice(projectFile, 0, 750) ]

        for p in pool:
            p.start()

        for n in projectFile:
            jobs.put(n.strip())

        for p in pool:
            jobs.put(None)

        count=0
        for p in pool:
            p.join()
            count += 1
            print count

        print results
```

Does anyone see anything that could be causing the deadlocks? I am pretty unsure of how to proceed as it all seems to check out in my head. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the variable pingables?, you have not declared anywhere.

Comment: @GabrielAlberto sorry, edited it a little before posting here and forgot about that one. pingables should be projectFile

Comment: can you put some part of 'file.txt' in the question to test?.

Comment: it's just a huge list of IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

I think that this problem is caused by creating multiple processes that. This is not necessarily a deadlock, but the algorithm is taking a long time to instantiate methods. I made a test with threads and apparently worked well faster. Look the code:

```
import multiprocessing
import itertools
import threading

def function(job, results):
    # do stuff
    results.put(stuff)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    devices = {}
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
        projectFile= f.readlines()

        jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
        results = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

        pool = [threading.Thread(target=function, args=(jobs, results)) for ip in itertools.islice(projectFile, 0, 750) ]

        for i,p in enumerate(pool):
            print "Started Thread Number", i  # Log to verify
            p.start()

        for n in projectFile:
            jobs.put(n.strip())

        for p in pool:
            jobs.put(None)

        count=0
        for p in pool:
            p.join() # This join is dangerous, make sure of the thread not raise any error
            count += 1
            print count

        print results
```

I dont know if this code will solve your problem, maybe will be executed more fast.